# Base Class or Interface for Custom Settings

Tags: class, customsetting, interface

Is exist Interface or Base class for Custom setting? I tried use SObject class, but it does not support Custom Settings Methods.

For any SObject we can use SObject class, that base class for standard and custom object.

```
SObject account = new Account();
```

We can use SObject for Custom Settings, but there are no specific Custom Setting methods

```
SObject settings = new MyCustomSettings__c();
```

What class contains specific Custom Settings methods?

Comment: Please explain your question in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

There is no base type that includes the [extra methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm) that custom settings support. This unfortunately means that if you want to write some code that applies to many of the custom settings, you will have to write it over again for each one. Or perhaps you could use the [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) with a small adapter class per custom setting to create your own consistent interface.

Comment: Thanks, I also couldn't find base class in documentation.

Comment: I can confirm that there's no such type, documented or otherwise. It's a cool idea; you might want to post it on the IdeaExchange.

Comment: @AvromRoy-Faderman In my experience development oriented ideas get few votes and are rarely implemented by Salesforce.

Comment: Actually it occurs to me that that might not make sense anyway.  The special custom settings methods are all static, so couldn't be exposed on an interface. And it wouldn't make sense to put the method on a base class, because what would it return?  You can't have abstract static methods.

Answer (score -1):

[Custom Settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm?search_text=custom%20setting#apex_methods_system_custom_settings) are part of the System Class and have their own methods. Using a [DescribeSObjectResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm?search_text=custom%20setting), they can be detected in the results when `isCustomSetting() == true`.

Comment: Yes, it is clear. But I want know exist either base class with specific custom settings methods, like getAll(). That I can use this class instead of specific custom setting type, e.g. SObject we can use instead of any other object type.

Comment: Click on "Custom Settings" in my answer above. That will take you to the methods available for use with custom settings. sObject methods are not available for use with Custom Settings, only those through the link I've provided.

Comment: "Custom Settings" is SObject with specific methods. I would like to know any Interface or Base Class for this methods.

Comment: Read the documentation. Even though a Custom Setting counts against an org's allocation of custom sObjects, it is NOT an sObject Class. It is part of the System Class and has it's own methods of which I've pointed you to the documentation.

Comment: Try to run following code in your Org:

    ApplicationSettings__c appSetting = new ApplicationSettings__c();
    System.debug((Object)appSetting instanceOf SObject);

ApplicationSettings__c - My Custom Settings

Comment: To be pedantic, System is a namespace, not a class.

Comment: Yes, custom settings classes are indeed subclasses of SObject. There is no common interface or base class that exposes their special methods.